# Video player for the site

Tags: html, video, mp4, video-player

I have to insert video into the site. The codec is mpeg4 (avi), I used http://github.com/zencoder/video-js as player (HTML5) with attributes:

```
<source src="some.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
```

This works great in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox, IE, etc. Any ideas, why? Or what I have to do? Maybe convert video to the webm or ogv? I Also tried some flash players (flow) but they don't support MP4 playing and flv quality is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ogv for firefox and opera. For IE (apart from IE9) it doesn't support HTML5. You have to have a Flashplayer to replace it. This is a really good page to read http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2009/2/using-the-html5-video-tag-with-a-flash-fallbac